# PrimeFaces with HTML/CSS Navigation Bug

Tags: html, css, layout

I have made a Homepage (HTML/CSS) and now I work with Primeface.

The big problem is that some Buttons are over the navigation.
So here you can see the problem:

[image]

In the second Picture: If you over the Arrow Buttons then the navigation disappeared.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Share your work so others can more efficiently help you with troubleshooting your issue. Just showing a picture is like taking your car to the mechanic and saying "Here, something is wrong so fix it.....but you can't look under the hood." :)

Comment: Change the z-index of the dropdown nav to a higher value than the calendar ex: `.dropdown-menu { z-indez: 2 }` `.calendar { z-index: 1 }`. That being said, if you can paste some of your code onto here it'd be a lot easier to help you solve the problem then just guessing that z-index could be the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use simply `z:index` for (calendar and menu)